# Java 8 Comparator nullsFirst naturalOrder confused

Tags: java, string, sorting, java-8, comparator

this may be a simple question but I would like to understand it clearly...

I have a code like this:

```
public final class Persona
{
   private final int id;
   private final String name
   public Persona(final int id,final String name)
   {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
   }
   public int getId(){return id;}    
   public String getName(){return name;}     
   @Override
   public String toString(){return "Persona{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name+'}';}    
 }
```

And I am testing this code:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.*;
private void nullsFirstTesting()
{               
    final Comparator<Persona>comparator = comparing(Persona::getName,nullsFirst(naturalOrder()));
    final List<Persona>persons = Arrays.asList(new Persona(1,"Cristian"),new Persona(2,"Guadalupe"),new Persona(3,"Cristina"),new Persona(4,"Chinga"),new Persona(5,null));
    persons
            .stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .forEach(System.out::println);                           
}
```

This shows the following results:

```
Persona{id=5, name=null}
Persona{id=4, name=Chinga}
Persona{id=1, name=Cristian}
Persona{id=3, name=Cristina}
Persona{id=2, name=Guadalupe}
```

These results are OK with me but I have a problem understanding.

When I ignore the `new Persona(5,null)` object and I pass the comparator:

```
final Comparator<Persona>comparator = comparing(Persona::getName);
```

It works like a charm. My sorting is by `natural order of name property`. The problem arises when I add the object with `name=null`, I just thought I would need my comparator like this.

```
final Comparator<Persona>comparator = comparing(Persona::getName,nullsFirst());
```

My thought was **erroneous**: "OK, when name is non-null, they are sorted in `natural order of name`, just like the previous comparator, and if they are `null` they will be first **but my non-null names will still be sorted in natural order**".

But the right code is this:

```
final Comparator<Persona>comparator = comparing(Persona::getName,nullsFirst(naturalOrder()));
```

I don't understand the parameter to `nullsFirst`. I just thought the `natural order of name` would explicitly [default] even handle `null` values.

But the docs say:

> Returns a null-friendly comparator that considers `null` to be
>   less than non-null. When both are `null`, they are considered
>   equal. If both are non-null, the specified `Comparator` is used
>   to determine the order. If the specified comparator is `null`,
>   then the returned comparator considers all non-null values to be equal.

This line: "If both are non-null, the specified `Comparator` is used to determine the order."

I am confused when and how the natural order should be explicitly set or when they are inferred.

Comment: Note *"If the specified comparator is `null`, then the returned comparator considers all non-null values to be equal."* In other words, you can do `nullsFirst(null)`; however it merely sorts the nulls to the front without sorting the non-nulls. The doc does actually explain it pretty well.

Comment: @chiperotiz so how did you solve it eventually? Were you able to sort by nulls first and then Natural order?

Comment: yes using this code `final Comparator<Persona>comparator = comparing(Persona::getName,nullsFirst(naturalOrder()));`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The "natural order" comparator, which is what you get when you use `comparing` with only one parameter, does *not* handle nulls.  (I'm not sure where you got the idea that it did.)  The "natural order" of a `Comparable` class is defined by the `compareTo()` method, which is used like this:

```
obj1.compareTo(obj2)
```

Obviously this won't work if `obj1` is null; for `String`, it will also throw an exception if `obj2` is null.

The `naturalOrder()` method returns a `Comparator` that compares two objects.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) explicitly says that this comparator throws `NullPointerException` when comparing null.

The `nullsFirst()` method (and `nullsLast()` similarly) basically transforms a `Comparator` to a new `Comparator`.  You put in a comparator that may throw an exception if it tries to compare null, and it spits out a new comparator that works the same way except that it allows null arguments.  So that's why you need a parameter to `nullsFirst`--because it builds a new comparator on top of an existing comparator, and you tell it what the existing comparator is.

So why doesn't it give you the natural order if you leave out the parameter?  Because they didn't define it that way.  `nullsFirst` is defined in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) to take a parameter:

```
static <T> Comparator<T> nullsFirst(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

I think that if the designers wanted to, they could have added an overload that takes no parameters:

```
static <T> Comparator<T> nullsFirst()  // note: not legal
```

that would be the same as using `nullsFirst(naturalOrder())`.  But they didn't, so you can't use it like that.

Comment: Hello ajb i never thought that the only parameter comparator would be handle nulls.. i just thought the nullsFirst() method would put the nulls first and the non-nulls would be sorted in a natural order as well... but as you said `static <T> Comparator<T> nullsFirst()  // note: not legal` simple is not legal. i just thought would nice as you said a nullFirst without parameters should be naturalOrder() as default.. thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Try:

```
final Comparator<Persona> comparator =
  comparing(Persona::getName, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()));
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a list of Employee with Student with name and id ..

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student s1 = new Student("1","Nikhil");
        Student s2 = new Student("1","*");
        Student s3 = new Student("1",null);
        Student s11 = new Student("2","Nikhil");
        Student s12 = new Student("2","*");
        Student s13 = new Student("2",null);
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(s1);
        list.add(s2);
        list.add(s3);
        list.add(s11);
        list.add(s12);
        list.add(s13);

        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName,Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));

        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Student student = (Student) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(student);
        }


    }

}
```

Produces output as

```
Student [name=*, id=1]
Student [name=*, id=2]
Student [name=Nikhil, id=1]
Student [name=Nikhil, id=2]
Student [name=null, id=1]
Student [name=null, id=2]
```