# Comparator based on different nullable fields of an object

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have an `Employee` object which contains two fields `name` and `jobTitle`. For sorting the employee objects, first priority should be on `jobTitle`, if `jobTitle` is null then the sorting should be based on name.

Below is the Employee object

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String jobTitle;
}
```

I used chained Comparator with `JobTitlecomparator` and `NameComparator` to achieve this:

```
public class EmployeeChainedComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    private List<Comparator<Employee>> listComparators;

    @SafeVarargs
    public EmployeeChainedComparator(Comparator<Employee>... comparators) {
        this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        for (Comparator<Employee> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(emp1, emp2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public class EmployeeJobTitleComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        if(emp1.getJobTitle() != null && emp2.getJobTitle() != null){
            return emp1.getJobTitle().compareTo(emp2.getJobTitle());
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class EmployeeNameComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
        return emp1.getName().compareTo(emp2.getName());
    }
}

public class SortingMultipleAttributesExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> listEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Tom", "Developer"));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Sam", null));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Tim", "Designer"));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Bob", null));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Peter", null));
        listEmployees.add(new Employee("Craig", "Programmer"));

        Collections.sort(listEmployees, new EmployeeChainedComparator(new EmployeeJobTitleComparator(), new EmployeeNameComparator()
                ));

        for(Employee emp : listEmployees){
            System.out.println("Employee Job: "+emp.getJobTitle()+" Employee Name: "+emp.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I should get the output like this

```
Employee Job: Designer Employee Name: Tim
Employee Job: Developer Employee Name: Tom
Employee Job: Programmer Employee Name: Craig
Employee Job: null Employee Name: Bob
Employee Job: null Employee Name: Peter
Employee Job null Employee Name: Sam
```

But I'm not getting the desired result as I expected. I'm getting the output like this

```
Employee Job Developer Employee Name Tom
Employee Job null Employee Name Sam
Employee Job Designer Employee Name Tim
Employee Job null Employee Name Bob
Employee Job null Employee Name Peter
Employee Job Programmer Employee Name Craig
```

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this?

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: Getting the output like this                                                          Employee Job Developer Employee Name Tom
Employee Job null Employee Name Sam
Employee Job Designer Employee Name Tim
Employee Job null Employee Name Bob
Employee Job null Employee Name Peter
Employee Job Programmer Employee Name Craig

Comment: Not sure if this is the whole issue, but calling the constructor of `EmployeeChainedComparator` is only passing `EmployeeJobTitleComparator`.  Try adding `EmployeeNameComparator` so it's included in the List.

Comment: @AndrewS I just updated my question by passing NameConstructor as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *either* of the titles is `null`, then the two `Employee`s will evaluate as equals, even if one of them is not null. That's not what you want. You want all `null` titles to be equal to each other, but not non-null values.

Replace your compare method with this:

```
public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2) {
    if(emp1.getJobTitle() == null && emp2.getJobTitle() == null){
        return 0;
    }
    if(emp1.getJobTitle() == null) return 1;
    if(emp2.getJobTitle() == null) return -1;
    return emp1.getJobTitle().compareTo(emp2.getJobTitle());
}
```

And you should get the results you expect.

Comment: Thanks @resueman I got the expected output with the above code

Answer (score 15):

Since you're using Java 8, you can use the built-in comparator facilities instead of creating your own comparators. Comparing the job title and then the name can easily be done with

```
Comparator<Employee> comparator =
     Comparator.comparing(Employee::getJobTitle).thenComparing(Employee:getName);
```

How to handle `null` values is also built-in with the [`nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) and [`nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) methods. Those methods wrap an existing comparator into a `null` safe comparator, putting `null` values either at the end or at the start.

As such, you can have:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;
import static java.util.Comparator.nullsLast;

// ...

Comparator<Employee> comparator = 
    comparing(Employee::getJobTitle, nullsLast(naturalOrder())).thenComparing(Employee::getName);

Collections.sort(listEmployees, comparator);
```

The comparator is created by [`comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) the job titles with a `null` safe comparator putting `null` values last ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350996/java-8-comparator-nullsfirst-naturalorder-confused)). For equal titles, it is [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-) the name of the employees.