# Working of Comparator.nullsFirst when both are null

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have a class with several "optional" (not `java.util.Optional`) fields. I was writing a Lambda comparator to test for equality by comparing a subset of their attributes

I wrote

```
private final static Comparator<MyEntity> COMPARATOR_491 =  
            comparing(MyEntity::getIsin)
             .thenComparing(MyEntity::getTMarketType)
             .thenComparing(nullsFirst(comparing(MyEntity::getIsoCode)))
             .thenComparing(MyEntity::getTaxRate)
             .thenComparing(nullsFirst(comparing(MyEntity::getEndDate)));
```

- ISIN is not null
- Market type is not null
- Is code can be null
- Tax rate is not null
- End date can be null

The problem is that often I get a `NullPointerException`. This is the (barely readable) stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$40/221702765.compare(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Comparator.java:217) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$42/770739971.compare(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Comparator.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$42/770739971.compare(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Comparator.java:216) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$42/770739971.compare(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

I found that two sample entities differ by the End date. The first entity has non-null property, the second has null

I thought that `nullsFirst` comparer could be null safe when one or both arguments are null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351410/471213

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The comparator returned by `nullsFirst(…)` returns a comparator which handles the case that one or both of the objects to compare are `null`.

So when you say `nullsFirst(comparing(MyEntity::getIsoCode))`, you get a comparator handling the case that either or both `MyEntity` instances are `null` and comparing the `getIsoCode` property according to their natural order (not handling `null` values), if neither `MyEntity` instance is `null`.

What you want achieve, is `comparing(MyEntity::getIsoCode, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))`, specify the `null`-safe comparator to be used to compare the property values. The same applies to the `getEndDate` property.

You may fuse it with `thenComparing`, to `previousComparator.thenComparing(MyEntity::getIsoCode, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))`

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion by myself after a little tinkering but I want to award you the accepted answer. I confused the working of nullsFirst/last in my first implementation