# Java Lambda sort with object properties throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

- Code when sorting with the Object property (which is another object), with null values though using he compartor `nullsFirst()` end up in null pointer exception.

```java
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AgeRange ageRange = new AgeRange();
        ageRange.setBegin(1);
        ageRange.setEnd(18);
        
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setAgeRange(age);
        
        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setAgeRange(null);
        
        AgeRange ageRange1 = new AgeRange();
        ageRange1.setBegin(19);
        ageRange1.setEnd(25);
        
        Person p3 = new Person();
        p3.setAgeRange(ageRange1);
        
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(p1);
        persons.add(p2);
        persons.add(p3);
        
        persons.stream().sorted(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAgeRange)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        //above throws null pointer exception
        
    }
}

  class Person {
        private String name;
        private AgeRange ageRange;
        
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        public AgeRange getAgeRange(){
            return this.ageRange;
        }
        
        public void setAgeRange(AgeRange ageRange){
            this.ageRange = ageRange;
        }
        
    }
    
    class AgeRange implements Comparable<AgeRange>{
        long begin;
        long end;
        
        public void setBegin(long begin){
            this.begin = begin;
        }
        
         public void setEnd(long end){
            this.end = end;
        }
        
        public long getBegin(){
            return this.begin;
        }
        
        public long getEnd(){
            return this.end;
        }
        
        @Override
        public int compareTo(AgeRange obj){
            return Long.compare(begin,obj.begin);
        }
    }
```

- exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
at java.base/java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:353)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:34)
```

Understood that an operation done using the null object, is there way's to sort the null first in this approach.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153431/2711488) You want `Comparator.comparing(Person::getAgeRange, Comparator.nullsFirst( Comparator.naturalOrder()))`. By the way, you’re not using the result of `collect`. If you just want to sort the list, don’t use a `Stream`. Use `persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAgeRange, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can try with this approach here:*

***Here,***

I have passed the `Comparator.nullsFirst` in the `Comparator.comparing()` which will have the nulls value first and then compare the rest of the values ignoring the null data.

You can also use `Comparator.reverseOrder()` if you want to have the reverse ordering of the data.

```
List<Person> sortedData = persons.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAgeRange,
  Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(sortedData);
```