# Getting the below exception on using the null first method of java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have the below program in which I am trying to print `null`. I am using Java 8 for this. Below is my code to achieve it:

```
            List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();                                
            personList.add(new Person("Alice", "alice@gmail.com", Gender.FEMALE, 15));
            personList.add(new Person("Bob", "bob@gmail.com", Gender.MALE, 16));           
            personList.add(new Person("Eric", "eric@gmail.com", Gender.MALE, 17));
            personList.add(new Person("Carol", "carol@gmail.com", Gender.FEMALE, 23));
            personList.add(new Person(null, "alice@gmail.com", Gender.FEMALE, 15));
            personList.add(new Person("Carol", "carol@gmail.com", Gender.FEMALE, 23));
            personList.add(new Person("David", "david@gmail.com", Gender.MALE, 19));
            personList.add(new Person("Bob", "bob@gmail.com", Gender.MALE, 16));
```

now below is the code that I have written to print the `null` name first:

```
personList.stream().sorted(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName))).forEach(System.out::println);
```

but I am getting the below exception, please advise how to overcome from this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
    at java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
    at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:221)
```

Comment: `forEach(System.out::println)` is the probable reason there.

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350996/java-8-comparator-nullsfirst-naturalorder-confused

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using comparator wrong. See this and shall work

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.Comparator.*;
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();                                
            personList.add(new Person("Alice", "alice@gmail.com"));
            personList.add(new Person("Bob", "bob@gmail.com"));           
            personList.add(new Person("Eric", "eric@gmail.com"));
            personList.add(new Person("Carol", "carol@gmail.com"));
            personList.add(new Person(null, "alice@gmail.com"));
            personList.add(new Person("Carol", "carol@gmail.com"));
            personList.add(new Person("David", "david@gmail.com"));
            personList.add(new Person("Bob", "bob@gmail.com"));
             System.out.println(personList);



            personList.stream().sorted(comparing(Person::getName, nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))).forEach(System.out::println);
     }
}
class Person
{
    private String name,email;
    Person(String name, String email)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String toString(){return name;}
}
```

Comment: May also have a look at this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350996/java-8-comparator-nullsfirst-naturalorder-confused

Comment: thx @Dustin. I was going to add more explanation. but your thread seems already have everything.

Answer (score 1):

The NPE is a result of passing a `null` value to `Comparator.comparing`

The Javadoc says

> @throws NullPointerException if the argument is null

Perhaps try something like

```
Comparator.comparing(Person::getName, Comparator.nullsFirst(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
```

Which produces

```
null
Alice
Bob
Bob
Carol
Carol
David
Eric
```